# Output of a simple number guessing game in c using while and do-while loop

Tags: c, random, while-loop, do-while

I am a beginner in C programming and I want some help with a right digit counter in a number guess game. In this game, a random secret number of 4 digits is generated and user has to guess it by entering different numbers. In this code, each digit of the user input is scanned and checked. If a digit of the secret number is found in input, the counter k adds 1 and so it should give number of guessed digits. Order is not important (at this stage). Problem: the game gives a smaller number of digits guessed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(){
setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);

int n=10000;
srand(time(NULL));
int r=rand()%n;//makes a random (secret) number

int d1,d2,d3,d4;//declares digits of the random number

d1=r/1000;//these 4 lines calculate separate digits of the random number
d2=(r-d1*1000)/100;
d3=(r-d1*1000-d2*100)/10;
d4=r-d1*1000-d2*100-d3*10;

char c;//declares char c which will be a digit of a number given by user (guess)

if(d1!=d2&&d1!=d3&&d1!=d4&&d2!=d3&&d2!=d4&&d3!=d4){//prevents using a random number which has some duplicate digits

 printf("Enter a number:");
 scanf("%c",&c);//scan first digit(character) of user's guess

 while(c!='\n'){//scan all digits(characters) of user's guess until new line
 int k=0;//initialize a counter of right guesses

 while(c!='\n'){//scan all digits(characters) of user's guess until new line
  c=getchar();//scan each character of a user's number
  int digit=c-48;//convert the character into digit by using its ASCII value

   if(digit==d1){//if user digit coincides with the first digit of random number add 1 to counter
    ++k;
   }
   else if(digit==d2){//if no, check if it coincides with second digit
    ++k;
    }
   else if(digit==d3){
    ++k;
   }
   else if(digit==d4){
    ++k;
   }

  }

 printf("number of guessed digits is %i\n",k);
 printf("secret number =%i\n\n",r);

 printf("Enter a new number:");//asks the user to try another number
 scanf("%c",&c);//scan new digit
 }
}

return 0;
```

}

Example of output:

Enter a number:2015
number of guessed digits is 2
secret number =4901

Enter a new number:4902
number of guessed digits is 2
secret number =4901

Enter a new number:4901
number of guessed digits is 3
secret number =4901

Enter a new number:

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Quite few things seems to be wrong with the logic.Just to get you to the right track.1) else if condition is only checked if the previous condition is false. 2) may be input the whole 4 digit number in one go, then split it into 4 digits,check each digit seprately in a loop with the four randomly generated digits and increment counter on each match.hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! The problem seems to be in scanf() - it scanned the first character and the getchar() scanned only the 3 remaining characters. Here are more details http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/169577-problem-guess-game-using-while-do-while-loops.html

Answer (score 0):

You are always losing the first digit since you use `getchar()` immediately after `scanf()` without checking the result of `scanf()`.
Move

```
c=getchar();
```

after the if-conditions.

Comment: Thanks! But I seem to have found a solutihttp://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/169577-problem-guess-game-using-while-do-while-loops.htmlon. Here is the fixed code(at the bottom)

Comment: Sorry, here is proper link : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/169577-problem-guess-game-using-while-do-while-loops.html